# Java arrays in methods

Tags: java

I'm making a method that take a list of arrays and finds the average of the numbers.
I know that my method works since I just moved it from my main method to the "average" method. I'm just having problems getting the array to work with the method.

I'm not sure if I'm wrong by calling the method by `average(a);`, or if it's because the method is written as `public static void average(double[] a){`

Could someone point me to the right direction?

```
public class Ass10{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("asdf");
        int a[] = {1, 2, 3,4};
        average(a);
      }

    public static void average(double[] a){
        int sum = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter<a.length;counter++){
            sum += a[counter];
        }
                System.out.println(sum/a.length)

        }
```

Comment: Why is it `average(double[] a)` and not `average(int[] a)`?

Comment: What is the error exactly ? I think Cratylus has the answer for you

Comment: Thanks Cratylus, that was the problem! I needed them both as either double or int.

Comment: What exception are you getting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing `public static void average(double[] a)` to `public static void average(int[] a)`

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `double` in Java are primitives and not Objects. Further their arrays are not covariant. (Co-variance of array mean if A extends B, then A[] extends B[])

Hence you cannot use `double[]` where `int[]` is required. 
This should do `public static void average(int[] a){`

Secondly, `sum += a[counter];` will cause loss of precision as `sum` is type `int` and `a` is of type `double`